# Calculate Percent Graphite/Grafana (missing numerator)

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have three series #A, #B, #C which are used to get a percent by tags in a Bar Gauge

Assume I have two tags in each time-series
(1) color = red, blue, green
(2) etc = foo, bar

**I want percent foo by color**

- Series #A has a filter for color, applies summarize(), and applies groupByTags(color)
- Series #B has a filter for color, a filter "etc=foo", applies summarize(), and applies groupByTags(color)
- Series #C is #B asPercent(#A)

The issue I have is my data sometimes has no etc=foo for a tag

When this occurs, I get an error since it cannot match the groups in #B with #A

How can I resolve this so the missing groubByTags in #B would show as 0%

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by making a new interim #C series of #A, which is scaled by 0

Then another interim #D series which groups #B and #C

The #E does the #D asPercent(#A)